# MS Surface Book Pro. Battery Died Suddenly

Tags: battery, battery-life, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a Windows Surface Book Pro. device. The battery was healthy and works for as much as I needed. Out of a sudden, the battery today does not work at all. If I plugged the cable, the device turns off. I tried to uninstall the batteries drivers from the device manager, then I restarted my computer, but nothing changed.

The icons does show the battery is charged at 97% and not empty as this image:
[image]

But when the cable is out, the device turns off.

I suspect that my batteries should work but there is something wrong. Ideally batteries will slow in performance then die. In my case, my batteries were perfect but in a day, they suddenly stopped working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sometimes they fail suddenly.

Comment: Batteries do that .  Is it replaceable?

Comment: yes, a computer service center can help

Comment: If the computer remains serviceable, replace the battery.  I just replaced the battery in my X230 (from 2013) Dr. Battery via Amazon. Work great. Use a service center or local shop to replace the battery in the Surface.

Comment: Thank you all for you replies. The insurance is expired. I do not see the battery myself as in normal laptops so I cannot just order one and plug it. It is integrated somehow.

Comment: Yes, the battery is integrated like my ThinkPad X1.  A shop can replace it

Answer (score 0):

Though there are online guides to battery replacement, e.g., [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOy9HwEXMO8), there are [numerous warnings](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-replace-the-battery-in-the-Surface-Book) that the process is difficult to perform without destroying the device. In particular, the LCD screen is likely to be damaged during removal.

Though a bit awkward, you might consider using an [external USB-C power bank](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08537MKBS) with [a charging cable](https://www.windowscentral.com/surface-connect-dongle-lets-your-charge-your-surface-over-usb-c). At ~US$180 for the two items (which I have **not** tried -- anyone with experience, *please* edit), it's not inexpensive, but far less than commercial repair prices I see online, and an external pack *could* give longer run-time than even the original internal battery. Check that those items are returnable if they do not work for your needs.